# Online font not loading

Tags: theme, frontend, design, font-family, fonts

I tried using a Adobe Typekit font with the following method. I add this to my `default_head_blocks.xml` inside my `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/oti3nzu.js" src_type="url"/>
<script src="js/typekit_loader.js"/>
```

the javascript file looks like this:

```
try {
Typekit.load({ 
    async: true 
    });
}catch(e){}
```

Then, in `<theme_dir>/web/css/source/_variables.less` I changed the font name to this:

```
//  Fonts
@font-family-name__base: 'niveau-grotesk';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;
```

Now, when I deploy my static content and reload the site (cache cleared) the font isn't applied. When I check the sourcecode I see this:

```
body {
color: #333;
font-family: "niveau-grotesk", 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial,  sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.42857143;
font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

The only thing I can think of that goes wrong is that in `_typography.less` it says:

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name: @font-family-name__base,
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300',
    @font-weight: 300,
    @font-style: normal
);
```

So the `font-path` is still the one that leads to opensans, it is just named differently in CSS now because of my changes inside the `_variables.less` file, right? But what should I put as path? I mean it's an online font and there is no path available to an actual font file.

What should I do?